# React Native Expo open in IOS

Tags: react-native

Im starting to learn React Native using Expo. I just installed expo-cli, code some of my app (react-router-native, some jsx).
When I scan the QR (that shows visual code terminal after npm start of the project) to test the app on my iphone, I get this error in the phone:

```
Unable to resolve "@ungap/url-search-params" from "node_modules\react-router-native\index.js"
```

I can not open it on my iphone. App works ok on web.

Any ideas?

Comment: Obviously it's a problem with dependencies but without showing your package.json, app.json and full logs only advice you can get is to make a proper cache cleanup and fresh build.

Comment: yes, the never old fashioned restart. it worked!